# CODEIGNITER Exception: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Please I have an issue with codeigniter. when I try to log here is the result:

Severity: error --> Exception: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean /home/euroyals/bdhospitals.com/amar-pharmacy/application/models/Reports.php 276

Below the code of the relative file:

```html
public function out_of_stock_count(){

    
  $this->db->select("b.manufacturer_name,a.product_name,a.generic_name,a.strength,((select ifnull(sum(quantity),0) from product_purchase_details where product_id= `a`.`product_id`)-(select ifnull(sum(quantity),0) from invoice_details where product_id= `a`.`product_id`)) as 'stock'");
       $this->db->from('product_information a');
       $this->db->join('manufacturer_information b','b.manufacturer_id=a.manufacturer_id','left');
         $this->db->having('stock < 10');
         $this->db->group_by('a.product_id');
         return $records = $this->db->get()->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because get() either returns a `ResultInterface` or `false` (https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/e31166e246a7b27ba555897ef87b9812c9a01195/system/Database/BaseBuilder.php#L1855)

In case of `false` you cannot call num_rows() on it (this is what the error message says)
Try something like this:

```
$result = $this->db->get();
return $result ? $result->num_rows() : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please give me a solution in case it returns a ResultInterface

Comment: This is already the full solution. The questionmark is a short if statement. So it means: if($result != false) return $result->num_rows(); else return 0;